# cmder can not run Contig with parameters

Tags: windows, command-line, cmder

I want to replace default cmd with cmder but cmder can't run Contig to defrag my frequently use folders on the hdd. The command is `Contig.exe -v -s E:\WarThunder` which run fine on cmd but it just pops out the help menu on cmder (like parse wrong parameters).

How can I fix this. Any ideas are welcome

Comment: Clarify the question. What do you run exactly and where? What pops out? Show screenshots.

Comment: Hi, I found the error is the path is not in double quotes and need to remove the last back slash in the path.

Answer (score 0):

Contig.exe (from SysInternal tools) has a severe bug: it does not detect the presence of symbolic links (or directory junctions) and of mounted volumes.
In some cases, the target file (or target directory for direction junctions) may not even exist, and in that cases it will crash by failing to get its extents generating a dump in the Crashdump directory of the current user.

Contig.exe should by default not follow the target of any symbolic link, or target of any directory junction, or the target if it is a mountpoint. Instead if should just analyse/defragment the link or junction or the mountpoint itself.

- If one wants to analyse/defragment the target of a symbolic link or junction, there should be an additional "-f" option to enable following such redirections. That option should be off by default.
- If one wants to analyse/defragment the target of a mount point, there should be an additional "-m" option to enable visiting them. That option should be off by default.
- if "-f" or "-m" options are used along with "-s" (which recurses subdirectories), contig.exe should track the visited path, by keeping the volume id and file id of each visited directory, and NEVER revisit the same nodes further (to avoid infinite recursion loops in the same visted parent directory already present in the stack).

Such similar bug was partially solved for the ATTRIB.EXE command line tool (with its "/L" option when it is used with "/S" for recursing subdirectories) however it still persists when there are mounted volumes in a mount point. For the ICACLS.exe tool, apparently this is handled correctly (it never visits the targets of links, but just the link itself), however it still has a problem with mountpoints (to a different volume, possibly in a VHDX, or to another directory of the current volume).

Such bugs affect other tools, notably backup/restore tools (including the legacy "Windows 7" backup still present in Windows 8/8.1/10/11, which may also fail to correctly and successfully create a file-based backup, including various symbolic links or junctions that are present by default in user profiles, but just marked with a legacy "hidden" attribute, or if they are not explicitly excluded from the list of subdirectories to NOT backup/restore)

Windows is still not fully tested for the complete and effective correct support of symbolic links (including "directory junctions" in NTFS). Hard links (supported in NTFS between files/directories on the same volume) may also be a problem where infinite recursion is possible. Windows still assumes in many places the behavior of legacy FAT filesystems, where any file or directory can only be accessed from a unique path; but let's remember that symbolic links and mountpoints (for directories) are existing since very long (they existed in IBM-DOS, MS-DOS or DR-DOS, and within various DOS extenders, on mounted FAT volumes or mounted network volumes, long before the 1st 16-bit releases of Windows!).

May be such bug of Contig.exe (and some its administrative privileges and its internal "licence check" that can popup an agreement dialogue) can cause "cmder" to refuse using Contig.exe (which is not purely a command line tool as it must be able to use the Windows desktop and not just the standard I/O streams)